# How to handle Route Not Found Exception in Laravel 8 api?

Tags: laravel, rest

I am using Laravel 8 and building API's. I have an issue am not able to handle Route Not found exception. I don't know how to handle in laravel 8.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        //
    });
}
```

Kindly help me.
If i type wrong url i face this error
[enter image description here][1]

But i want to display error message in response
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qC9h.png

Comment: Welcome to SO...   You need to be more specific - trying to access which route do you get the error. Pls post the code of your routes file as well

Comment: I am using postman to hit api's. I want if any wrong url hit in post man i get specfic message. But this time my application has been crashed.

Comment: In previous version of laravel App\Exception\handle contain handle method. But in laravel it is register i also read documentation but i cannot understand.

Comment: @Donkarnash I have update my Question

Comment: so basically you want to throw 404 not found exception for any random string for your route

Comment: Yes i want to display simple message

Comment: I think this may help you https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Comment: Thanks for your help but i want that if i hit post or get request and my url is http://localhost/invoice/show/123 and i type http://localhost/invooooooice/show/123 then i show message route not exist or other message

Comment: instead of register try to extend the render method of exceptionhandler, I can give you an example

Comment: Ok i am waiting for your answer

Comment: Thanks alot now i have write handle method its work thanks again

Comment: so you extended the exception handler class methods

Comment: Yeah i extend method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [fallback method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes) for Route class in the documentation, it should satisfy what you need without using exceptions.

This is what is written in docs

> Using the Route::fallback method, you may define a route that will be executed when no other route matches the incoming request.

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return abort(404);
    // return view('errors.404');  // incase you want to return view
});
```

There is also the method of extending the render method of exception handler but I guess this satisfies your needs.